# Creating trigger Dynamically in APEX

Tags: dynamic, triggers, apex-code

I want to create trigger dynamically in my apex class.
 Can anyone here help me..
 Please guide me for this.
 I am fresher for visual force pages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot created trigger dynamically in Apex. Because Apex code has no access to the Trigger object So, you can not create triggers programmatically. Anyways we never need to create trigger dynamically.  Look here: http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/Create-Trigger-dynamically/td-p/667868

Sample apex code to create a trigger by Tooling API endpoint using REST callout:

```
        String json = '{ "Name" : "COTrigger", \'+
                             '"TableEnumOrId" : "Custom_Object__c",'+
                             '"Body" : "trigger COTrigger on Custom_Object__c (after insert) { // Do Something }" }'; // JSON format to create trigger

            Httprequest req = new HttpRequest();
            req.setEndpoint('https://[salesforce instance].salesforce.com/services/data/v27.0/sobjects/ApexTrigger');
            req.setMethod('POST');
            req.setHeader('Content-Type':'application/json');
            req.setHeader('Authorization':'Bearer: '+sessionId);
            req.setBody(json);

        Http httpReq = new HttpReq();
        HttpResponse res = httpReq.send(req); 
        System.debug(res.getBody());
```

Correct some syntax error, Tooling API is basically a set of Objects, components accessible through it. Try this code, Actually I used this code to create Apex class not Apex Trigger and here i just changed body & endpoint to make it work for trigger. If it doesn't work it means creating Trigger from Tooling API is still not supported.

Read this guide http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_toolingpre/api_tooling.pdf It has all about tooling API and not any complex configuration is required to do this. You only need to **REST callout** on endpoint url to create trigger. Endpoint url are provided in guide, of which link i have given.

Comment: That was my post only...Thank you

Comment: No..but I want to know that with my requirement , how do I use Tooling API ? Somebody has given me this link
http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9603/how-do-i-use-the-tooling-api-to-create-a-new-apex-trigger

Comment: You can create Apex Trigger by Tooling API but before using Tooling API, you must know SOAP API and REST API. By the way, what's your requirement?

Comment: I want to create trigger dynamically.
Basically my requirement is :I am creating custome objects dynamically throgh metadata services.
 Now whenever my new CO done, my trigger should also be created dynamically.

Comment: I am not having any idea about Tooling API. What should I configure in my salesforce for using Tooling API ? I have tired by putting your given code in console . But how it will take  Httprequest ? I have not configured my salesforce..

Comment: Is your organization has API enabled?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36089/discussion-between-khushbu-and-ashwin)

Comment: @khushbu Do you able to create trigger now?

Comment: with this code : "Name" : "COTrigger", \'+
                             '"TableEnumOrId" : "Custom_Object__c",'+
                             '"Body" : "trigger COTrigger on Custom_Object__c (after insert)

Comment: I am able to create trigger from Postman ...Thanks a lot for help

Comment: can u please tell me how can i edit trigger ? (body).I have given this link in Postman for updating trigger dynamically   :  https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/data/v28.0/sobjects/ApexTrigger/query/?q=Select+Name+from+ApexTrigger+Where+Name==\' COTriggerEmp11'\

Comment: It is throwing me error : {
        "message": "Provided external ID field does not exist or is not accessible: query",
        "errorCode": "NOT_FOUND"
    }

Comment: can you please let me know how can I create and delete Apex class same way?

Comment: @Ashwani I am getting this error with the above example . "this session is not valid for use with the rest api"